# Wiring for a SFP rj45

Tags: sfp, wiring, rj45

I have a CISCO Catalyst 3560G and I bought two SFP to RJ45 Copper Module for Cisco GLC-T/SFP-GE-T Gigabit 1000Base-T Transceiver. I plugged one Module into the CISCO switch and the other into a Trendnet switch.

I cannot get the CISCO switch to make the port active.

I'm currently using a T586B pinout Cat6 cable, does it need to be wired differently?

Comment: An SFP RJ45 needs exactly the same type of cable and connections as a standard RJ45 socket.

I'm not familiar with Cisco hardware, but check the compatibility list for the switch to ensure it's compatible with the transceiver you've installed, and check the switch settings to make sure the port isn't disabled. The issue isn't your cable though, unless it's literally a bad cable.

Comment: Thanks, I've ordered a Genuine Cisco SFP RJ45 module from ebay. Should arrive in two weeks. Hope that works.